# EspoCRM - Page loading issue with 409 error

Tags: php, http, http-status-code-409, espocrm

Recently I started using open source version of EspoCRM(Version 5.7.11) and it was all working fine. But recently some interfaces are not being loaded(Customers records table/grid view, Create new customer view, Edit customer view, Portal user edit view etc.).

When a view is not being loaded, it shows following error in the browser console[attachment].

```
"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 409"
"Uncaught Error: Could not load file 'client/modules/crm/src/views/contact/fields/accounts.js?r=1581325536'"
```

I found that 409 Conflicts are most likely to occur in response to a **PUT request**. For example, you may get a 409 response when uploading a file which is older than the one already on the server resulting in a version control conflict. But in my case this is a **GET request** which is trying to access a javascript file.

This occurs only on certain computers while on some other computers, these 409 errors are not present and my EspoCRM instance is working fine.

I tried clearing cache and rebuilding options inside EspoCRM. But no luck.

Files that are returning 409 error have 644 permission and folders have 755 permission. Any idea on what is causing HTTP 409 error?

P.S. Why am I asking this question here and not in EspoCRM support forum? Because I already did and nobody responded so far. So really appreciate if you could shed some light on this.

Comment: this error related to the hosting server security setting, you have to contact the server support or change the hosting itself

Comment: @EymenElkum could you elaborate more please. As per the hosting environment, a hostgator shared hosting plan is used here. To be frank I don't have a clue what's causing this error since the javascript file in question is not something that is being updated from time to time. It's rather an static file. And I don't know if hostgator would be flexible with their security settings if this is caused by a security setting in the first place.

Comment: @EymenElkum Thank you for your answer. I was able to sort it out after contacting hostgator. It was due to mod_security. Thanks again.